# Updating bottom constraint with SnapKit and Swift 4

Tags: swift, snapkit

Here is my code. I am using KeyboardHelper library for managing keyboard states and getting keyboard height, and also SnapKit. I have a text field that triggers keyboard. When a keyboard is visible I want to raise blue box above keyboard bounds, so it's visible. So far I failed to do so. Can you please help me with my code?

```
private var keyboardHelper : KeyboardHelper?
let box = UIView()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    keyboardHelper = KeyboardHelper(delegate: self)

    guard let superview = self.view else {
        return
    }

    box.backgroundColor = UIColor.blue
    superview.addSubview(box)

    box.snp.makeConstraints { make in
        make.bottom.equalTo(superview.snp.bottom).offset(-16)
        make.width.equalTo(200)
        make.centerX.equalTo(superview)
        make.height.equalTo(100)
    }
}

func keyboardWillAppear(_ info: KeyboardAppearanceInfo) {
    UIView.animate(withDuration: TimeInterval(info.animationDuration), delay: 0, options: info.animationOptions, animations: {
        self.box.snp.updateConstraints({ make in
            make.bottom.equalTo(info.endFrame.size.height).offset(10)
        })
        self.box.layoutIfNeeded()
    }, completion: nil)
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to SnapKit docs:

> if you are only updating the constant value of the constraint you can use the method snp.updateConstraints

You need to use `snp.remakeConstraints` in your case. Furthermore, you should probably call `layoutIfNeeded` on `superview`.

Optionally you could get rid of changing constraints and just animate proper transforms on show:

```
box.transform = CGAffineTransform(translationX: 0.0, y: neededTranslation)
```

on hide:

```
box.transform = .identity
```